# NetSuite Oauth Implemenation

Tags: netsuite

I am looking for the oauth implemenation in Netsuite.Does Netsuite Supports oauth ? I searched for oath implementation in NetSuite but didn’t have a single result.

Is there any official documentation saying netsuite doesnt support oauth?

Answer (score 4):

NetSuite's SuiteTalk API does support oAuth, although it's implemented very differently from other services (google, stripe, etc). Acquiring oauth credentials requires the user to run through a non-obvious process and copy/paste four separate keys. I've written up a [guide detailing how to setup NetSuite SuiteTalk API with oAuth](http://mikebian.co/using-netsuites-token-based-authentication-with-suitetalk/).

Answer (score 3):

In 15.1 NetSuite supports inbound RESTlet calls with OAuth 1.0 tokens (be aware that it's not full OAuth 1.0 protocol, though it utilizes its token and header format). In NetSuite you can get access token in two ways - either call token endpoint, either manually from the UI. 
The good thing is that you can still use OAuth 1.0 open source libraries, like scribe for Java or oauth-1.0a.js, in the case if you plan to call RESTlets from node.js or SuiteScript (e.g. Suitelets)

PS Just look for Token-based Authentication for RESTlets

Comment: FWIW - The documentation is in the help once you're logged into your instance of Netsuite (You **must be logged in**). Hit the help button and goto SuiteCloud -> SuiteScript -> Understanding NetSuite SuiteScript Types -> RESTlets. There you'll find more detail.

Comment: @Kikoz Can you please elaborate the OAuth / Token implementation introduced in Netsuite 15.1.

Answer (score 3):

**Netsuite Does Support OAuth**, You can call a Restlet from an outside application with OAuth. There are lots of things that need to be configured in order for it to work, its pretty complex so I wrote this step by step guide.
 [Check out the step by step instructions](https://medium.com/@morrisdev/netsuite-token-based-authentication-tba-342c7df56386).

> **Basic code to Configure the Signature & header**

```
var NETSUITE_ACCOUNT_ID = '1234567890_SB'
var BASE_URL = 'https://1234567890_SB.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl'
var HTTP_METHOD = 'POST'
var SCRIPT_ID = '613'
var OAUTH_VERSION = '1.0';
var SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID = '1'
var TOKEN_ID = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0987654321"
var TOKEN_SECRET = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0987654321"
var CONSUMER_KEY = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0987654321"
var CONSUMER_SECRET = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0987654321"
var text = "";
var length = 32;
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
var OAUTH_NONCE = text;
var TIME_STAMP = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000);
var data = '';
data = data + 'deploy=' + SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID + '&';
data = data + 'oauth_consumer_key=' + CONSUMER_KEY + '&';
data = data + 'oauth_nonce=' + OAUTH_NONCE + '&';
data = data + 'oauth_signature_method=' + 'HMAC-SHA1' + '&';
data = data + 'oauth_timestamp=' + TIME_STAMP + '&';
data = data + 'oauth_token=' + TOKEN_ID + '&';
data = data + 'oauth_version=' + OAUTH_VERSION + '&';
data = data + 'script=' + SCRIPT_ID;
var encodedData = encodeURIComponent(data);
var completeData = HTTP_METHOD + '&' + encodeURIComponent(BASE_URL) + '&' + encodedData;
var hmacsha1Data = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(completeData, CONSUMER_SECRET + '&' + TOKEN_SECRET);
var base64EncodedData = Base64.stringify(hmacsha1Data);
var oauth_signature = encodeURIComponent(base64EncodedData);
var OAuth = 'OAuth oauth_signature="' + oauth_signature + '",';
OAuth = OAuth + 'oauth_version="1.0",';
OAuth = OAuth + 'oauth_nonce="' + OAUTH_NONCE + '",';
OAuth = OAuth + 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",';
OAuth = OAuth + 'oauth_consumer_key="' + CONSUMER_KEY + '",';
OAuth = OAuth + 'oauth_token="' + TOKEN_ID + '",';
OAuth = OAuth + 'oauth_timestamp="' + TIME_STAMP + '",';
OAuth = OAuth + 'realm="' + NETSUITE_ACCOUNT_ID + '"';
var request = https.post({
url: BASE_URL + '?script=' + SCRIPT_ID + '&deploy=' + SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID,
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": OAuth },
body: JSON.stringify({ hello: "world" })
})
var response = JSON.parse(request.body)
log.debug('response', response)
```

Comment: wondering if there a java version for the above OAuth authentication?

Answer (score 0):

No oauth option right now (if you are talking about application that you generate secret key, etc)

Netsuite only have webservices SOAP, RESTlet for integration option.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, NetSuite does in fact offer Oauth when the user is leaving to go to another application (3rd party application).

It does not support it coming in, coming in to NetSuite from a 3rd party. For that, you will want to use SAML, which it does now support as of the release (2012.3) before the release we are on now (2013.1) and reportedly works. We are deploying SAML here internally against Microsoft AD FS but are only half way there, but we will get it, and we will use it, and like it.

You need to be logged-in to NetSuite and then hit Support and then search on SAML to see these doc's.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: There is no 2012.3 released. Did our account miss anything?

Comment: I believe there was a 2012.3

Answer (score 0):

Inbound Single Sign On may be what you want to look at?

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteCloudCustomizationScriptingWebServices/SingleSignon/SingleSignonOverview-ch.html